# Display Name instead of Id in a GridView whose value is there in different table using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview

I have a GridView in which i am displaying Grid based on selected customer Name and in the grid i have a customer ID instead of that customet ID i need to display customer Name whose value is in Different Table how to achieve it using asp.net.
[image]

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#2A3F54" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
   runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%" Height="100%" CellSpacing="30" CellPadding="50" OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging">
   <Columns>
       <asp:BoundField DataField="collection_id" HeaderText="Collection Id" ItemStyle-Width="30" ItemStyle-Height="35" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="customer_id" HeaderText="Customer Name" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="collection_type" HeaderText="Collection Type" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="collection_date" HeaderText="Collection Date" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="collection_amt" HeaderText="Collection Amount" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="collection_chqno" HeaderText="Collection Cheque Number" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="collection_chdate" HeaderText="Collection Cheque Date" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="collection_refno" HeaderText="Collection Ref Number" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="collection_note" HeaderText="Collection Note" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="status" HeaderText="Status" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="updated_by" HeaderText="Updated By" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="updated_on" HeaderText="Updated On" ItemStyle-Width="150" />                        
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>



    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      string customerText = customerDetails.SelectedItem.Value;
      string query = @"select * from app_collection_master where customer_id="+customerText;             

        using (DataTable dt = SMSDBHelperFE.ExecuteReaderDataTable(CommandType.Text, query, null))
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();                
        }
    }
```

Now i am able to display Id but instead if Id i need to display name How to achieve i.

Comment: In which table customer name is saved?

Comment: @AA in `app_customer` table

Comment: please try the sample i have given in Answer section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the select query, join the table where customer name is stored. like

```
select * from app_collection_master inner join customerTable on customerTable.customerId=app_collection_master.customer_id where app_collection_master.customer_id="+customerText;
```

Then in the grid bind customer name

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="customer_name" HeaderText="Customer Name" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
```

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where app_collection_master.customer_id = 1' at line 1` i got this error

Comment: oh you are using mysql? but the queries are almost similar

Comment: post the full query pls

Comment: what i need to do now??

Comment: thats all the query i am using

Comment: Try this query. Change the column names according to your table.   select * from app_collection_master inner join app_customer on app_customer.customerId=app_collection_master.customer_id where app_collection_master.customer_id="+customerText;

Comment: yes thats working perfect please change in answer i will mark it accepted. Thank you for your time

Comment: Hi @A A i also need to join another column into this can you help me with this . I have a user id in app_collection and that also i need to display name

Comment: add an inner join to the table app_collection. I dont know which field is common in your tables to join. If you are not able to find a solution, post your table structure